# css bootstrap "Contextual backgrounds" shows with no padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use [css bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). I want to use the "Contextual backgrounds" block like the docs show.

Here is a screenshot from the docs
[image]

So I tried to do something like this:

```
<div>
    <p class="bg-warning">
        Now the following question can be answered on a scale of 1 to 10 where "1" means "Poor" and "10" means "Excellent" or any number in between.
    </p>
</div>
```

The problem is that the block is showing with no padding. The block shows with the correct background but it does not have the padding.

I know I can manually add style to add the padding, but I should not have to do that. Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is a screenshot of what the code is showing:

[image]

Comment: If you inspect one of those elements on the bootstrap site, you'll see that `.bs-example-bg-classes p` is given padding of 15px. Contextual backgrounds just provide the background and text colors.

Comment: @BrianRay thank you for the hint. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example from the Bootstrap documentation uses some custom classes to show the background colors in a custom container. By default, `bg-primary`, `bg-success`, etc only define the `background-color` attribute of the element they are applied to.

If you want the padding, you can use one of these other alternatives.

**Alerts**

```
<div class="alert alert-warning">
  <p style="color:black;">Now the following question can be answered on a scale of 1 to 10 where "1" means "Poor" and "10" means "Excellent" or any number in between.</p>
</div>
```

**List Groups**

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning" style="color:black;">Now the following question can be answered on a scale of 1 to 10 where "1" means "Poor" and "10" means "Excellent" or any number in between.</li>
</ul>
```

**Panels**

```
<div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <p class="panel-title" style="color:black;">
        Now the following question can be answered on a scale of 1 to 10 where "1" means "Poor" and "10" means "Excellent" or any number in between.
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note: Using `style="color:black;"` changes the text color to black, as the default yellow text on yellow background looks a little silly (but feel free to change it to your liking.)*

And here's a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/NDYA4UEbLJ) to show these in action.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the bootply :)